# Problems Integrating Head.js with jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, head.js

I'm trying to integrate just the javascript loader portion of head.js with my JQM website.

I'm having a couple of issues:

1. On some pages, I'm seeing the script block that I'm trying to load with head.js loaded 3-4 times on the page.
2. On all pages, I'm seeing a substantial period of unstyled content (FOUT). The styling does eventually load.

Here's some sample code that illustrates each issue:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html> 
    <html> 
    <head> 
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0">
    <title>Main Menu</title> 

    <!-- JQM CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />

    <!-- Custom Theme CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/cayce.css" />

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css" />

    <script src="js/head.load.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    head.js("http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js", "js/custom.js", "http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js");
    </script>

    </head>  
    <body>
    <div data-role="page" id="landing">

    <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Main Menu</h1>
    <div class="header-sub">
    <div class="logo">
    <a href="WebCatPageServer.exe?Landing">
    <img src="themes/images/logo.png" width="100" height="49" alt="Company Logo">
    </a>
    </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Search Bar-->
    <div class="ui-body ui-body-b">
    <fieldset>
    <form name="Search" id="searchform" method="post" action="WebCatPageServer.exe">
    <input name="Action" type="hidden" value="Search"/>
    <input name="PrevSearchText" type="hidden" value="" />
    <input name="Start" type="hidden" value="1" />
    <input name="New" type="hidden" value="YES" />
    <input name="Refine" type="hidden" value="NO" />
    <label for="search-basic"></label>
    <input type="search" name="Search Term" id="search-basic" placeholder="Enter Part #'s or Keywords" tabindex="1"/>
    </form>
    </fieldset>
    </div><!-- /Search Bar -->

    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
    <li><a href="SPI_TOCLink" data-theme="c">Browse Products</a></li>

    <!-- SPI_HTML_ShowSearchMenu -->
    <li><a href="SPI_SearchLink" id="SPI_CurrMenuSearch" data-prefetch>SPI_SearchMenuText</a></li>
    <!-- SPI_HTML_ShowSearchMenu -->

    <!-- SPI_HTML_AllowKits -->
    <li><a href="SPI_KitsLink" data-theme="c" id="viewjobs" data-prefetch>View Jobs</a></li>
    <!-- SPI_HTML_AllowKits -->

    <!-- SPI_HTML_AllowOrderPlacement -->
    <li><a href="SPI_ShopingCartLink" data-theme="c" data-prefetch>Shopping Cart</a></li>
    <!-- SPI_HTML_AllowOrderPlacement -->

    <!-- SPI_HTML_AllowSales -->
    <li><a href="SPI_SalesLink" id="SPI_CurrMenuSales" data-prefetch>SPI_SalesMenuText</a></li>
    <!-- SPI_HTML_AllowSales -->

    <!-- SPI_HTML_ShowMyAccountMenu -->
    <li><a href="SPI_MyAccountLink" data-theme="c" data-prefetch>SPI_MyAccountMenuText Dashboard</a></li>
    <!-- SPI_HTML_ShowMyAccountMenu -->

    <li><a href="SPI_LogoutLink">Logout</a></li>

    </ul><!-- /listview -->
    </div><!-- /Content--> 

    <div data-role="footer">

    </div><!-- /footer -->
    </div><!-- /page -->
    </body>
    </html>


     <!DOCTYPE html> 
        <html> 
        <head> 
        <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0">
        <title>Login</title> 

        <!-- JQM CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />

        <!-- Custom Theme CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/cayce.css" />

        <!-- Custom CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css" />

        </head>  
        <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="login">

        <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <div class="header-sub">
        <div class="logo">
        <a href="WebCatPageServer.exe?Landing">
        <img src="themes/images/logo.png" width="100" height="49" alt="Company Logo">
        </a>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">
        <div class="ui-bar text-center">
        <p>Please enter your <strong>Username</strong> and <strong>Password</strong> below to log in to the SPI_Cname Mobile Web Store.</p>
        </div>

        <!-- SPI_HTML_UnknownLogin
        <div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e text-center">
        <br>
        <h2>Please Try Again</h2>
        <p>Either the Username or Password you entered doesn't match our records. Please try logging in again.</p>
        </div>
        <br>
        SPI_HTML_UnknownLogin -->

        <!-- SPI_HTML_ExpiredLogin
        <div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e text-center">
        <br>
        <h2>Please Log In Again</h2>
        <p>Either your session has expired or you logged in on another computer. Please log in again.</p>
        </div>
        <br>
        SPI_HTML_ExpiredLogin -->

        <!-- SPI_HTML_SessionLogout
        <div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e text-center">
        <br>
        <h2>You've Logged Out.</h2>
        <p>You have successfully logged out of SPI_Cname online.</p>
        </div>
        <br>
        SPI_HTML_SessionLogout -->

        <div class="ui-body ui-body-c">
        <form name="Form" method="post" action="WebCatPageServer.exe">
        <input name="Action" type="hidden" value="Login" class="hidden" />
        <input name="Request" type="hidden" value="SPI_PageRequest" />

        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" tabindex="1" value=""/>
        </div>

        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" tabindex="2" value=""/>
        </div>

        <div data-role="controlgroup" style="width:100%; text-align:center">
        <input name="loginbutton" type="submit" data-theme="b" style="width:100%;" value="Sign In" tabindex="3"/>
        </div>

        </form>
        </div><!-- /ui-body ui-body-c -->

        <br>

        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
        <!-- SPI_HTML_GuestLogin
        <li><a href="href="javascript:document.Form.Username.value='guest';document.Form.Password.value='guestpassword';document.Form.submit();">Guest Login</a></li>
        SPI_HTML_GuestLogin -->
        <li><a href="tel://SPI_CPNum">Call Us: SPI_CPNum</a></li>
        <li><a href="WebCatPageServer.exe?Account_Request" id="accountrequest">Request Online Account</a></li>
        </ul><!-- /listview -->

        </div><!-- /content -->

        <div data-role="footer">

        </div><!-- /footer -->

        <!-- Start headjs -->
        <script src="js/head.load.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        head.js("http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js", "js/custom.js", "http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js", function() {
        $('#login').on('pageshow', function () {
        $(':input:visible:enabled:first').focus();
        });

        });<!-- End headjs -->
        </script>  
        </div><!-- /page -->
        </body>
        </html>
```

A few things to note:

1. I have ajax disabled globally.
2. I'm using a single page template (multiple pages).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

FOUC/FOUT is typical with frameworks like jQuery Mobile & jQuery UI, since they apply styling programatically once the dom is ready.

Try removing headJS, and inserting your jquery & mobile directly. If there is no difference, then it's just because that's how they work.

And if you still see the FOUC/FOUT, try looking into some frameworks like 320up, bootstrap & similar, as they are CSS based frameworks, not javascript based ones.

The golden rule normally is CSS on TOP, JS in the BOTTOM